# How could I open specific ports?

Tags: php, port, ports

I add this Webchat Client to my site according to this https://integra-scm.atlassian.net/wiki/display/UC/Webchat+Client+v6

The problem is how I do this?

> The following ports have to be redirected from the Public IP
>
> - 8089 TCP (SIP signaling by websocket) to the telephony server.
> - 443 For the webchat to the uContact Server.

When I do this in the site

```
<?php if(fsockopen("hostname",8089)){print "I can see port 8089";}else{print "I cannot see port 8089";} ?>
```

get the result

> I cannot see port 8089.

Comment: There is probably no service running on that port

Comment: So how I redirected from the public IP to that ports? thank you @C0dekid